# How to override this parallax?

Tags: html, css

Is it work to override the icon dog in this parallax? I want to see the icon dog whole body over the section, I do all my best but I'll wasted my time. see the code on bottom. can you correct my code if i'm wrong. Best regards Thanks.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
}
.Parallax {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 600px;
}
.Parallax:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  will-change: transform;

}
.Parallax h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
p{
  color: #fff;
}
.Parallax-image-1:before {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqgknPHfXngK5Rm8foHqsR-K5J5yAKa-njp2XC5cGCjtmRo__KEw);
}

.Parallax-image-2:before {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSwu_ZX03m-x1IOFgD38wHyuHkXbwSizX7PmHpW5phV3pQpoNqIpQ);
}
.imgoverflow{
height: 200px;
margin-top: -30vmin; 
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <section class="Parallax Parallax-image-1">
      <h1>Title Text</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="Parallax">
    <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ecM/d94/ecMd945ei.png" height="300px" class="imgoverflow">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>

    <section class="Parallax Parallax-image-2">
      <h1>Title Text</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="Parallax">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you want to achieve. Maybe show it in a mockup screenshot?

Comment: I want look like this on photo 

this the link screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4bQQYQRVLMneVQyUXVpdXBmcms

Comment: Please help me how to solve that problem. thanks

Comment: Much better if you can view my code snippet fullpage to see want I mean.. compared to this photoshop screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bQQYQRVLMneVQyUXVpdXBmcms/view?pref=2&pli=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually this is not a parallax ;)

but nevertheless, to get what you want, 3 things:

1. In the `.Parallax:before` area change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`
2. Take out `overflow: hidden` from the `.Parallax` area
3. Add to both `.Parallax-image-1:before` and `.Parallax-image-2:before` following rule: `position: fixed`

In complete it will look like this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
}
.Parallax {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 600px;
}
.Parallax:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  will-change: transform;

}
.Parallax h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
p{
  color: #fff;
}
.Parallax-image-1:before {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqgknPHfXngK5Rm8foHqsR-K5J5yAKa-njp2XC5cGCjtmRo__KEw);
  position: fixed;
}

.Parallax-image-2:before {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSwu_ZX03m-x1IOFgD38wHyuHkXbwSizX7PmHpW5phV3pQpoNqIpQ);
  position: fixed;
}
.imgoverflow{
height: 200px;
margin-top: -30vmin; 
}
```

Comment: Its not working sir like what I want to the output.. but anyway thanks sir.

Comment: I tested it. What did you want to output differently? At least you should see the whole image

Comment: this is the output what  mean https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bQQYQRVLMneVQyUXVpdXBmcms/view?pref=2&pli=1 look the dog in left side. i want to see whole image.

Comment: i want to override the image on left side not the background.. like overflow: visible.. do you get my point?

Comment: overflow visible lets you show the image. but in your case the :before lies on top of it because it is positioned fixed (so not related in top and left to its parent but the document body instead). make the :before absolute and only the 2 before with the images inside fixed just as I told you. do everything i told you and it will work, just tested it in your example. looks like in screenshot

Comment: this image http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ecM/d94/ecMd945ei.png i want to overflow as visible sir in the second section.

Comment: yes. that is what my code is doing...you see the whole dog. just replace your css snippet with mine and send me the link. i will take a look if i made a mistake or if you did

Comment: the dog in the left side is not there. its hidden.

Comment: i see. it's a z-index problem. take out the z-index 10 for all .parallax elements and add a z-index only to section 2 and section 4 (those with text and dog)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ec3tgddz/ this sir looks okay but how to top up the dog in left side? then check the text sir.. i dont know what happen. all text in setion 2 and 4 is hidden.

Comment: nice, we're getting closer. you still need the  z-index: -1; on the .Parallax:before to work. put that line back into the code

Comment: Wow nice sir exactly.. Thank you so much. :) How can I compensate to you?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ec3tgddz/2/ thank you so much for your helping sir :) -thumbsup-

Comment: you called me Sir several times. also you marked my answer as correct. more than i expected ;) have fun!

Comment: Sir  user6292372 Can I ask one question again i saw some issue this the link https://jsfiddle.net/ec3tgddz/2/. look at the 2nd background it cannot change.. same background from the first one.. thanks in advance sir :)